# Get all tables in SQL Server database except some selected ones?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to display names of all tables in mySQL Server database with the exception of three selected ones. In MySQL I used a Query like:

```sql
SHOW TABLES FROM " + self.databaseName + " WHERE tables_in_" + self.databaseName + " NOT LIKE 'shots' AND tables_in_" + self.databaseName + " NOT LIKE 'conditions' AND tables_in_" + self.databaseName + " NOT LIKE 'analysis'"
```

Is there an equivalent in SQL Server?

Comment: Consider using the catalog views in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema. The same query will work in MySQL, SQL Server, and other DBMS products that support the ISO standard views.

Answer (score 1):

Use the system tables:

```
SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
       t.[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.[name] NOT IN (N'Table1',N'Table2','Table3');
```

You can also use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does suggest you use the `sys` objects:

```
SELECT T.TABLE_SCHEMA,
       T.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE T.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (N'Table1',N'Table2','Table3')
  AND T.TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE';
```

Note, that if the tables you want to omit are in specific schemas and you have objects with the same name on different schemas you don't want to exclude, you would need to use `AND` clauses in the `WHERE`:

```sql
WHERE NOT(s.[name] = N'dbo' AND t.[name] = N'Table1')
  AND NOT(s.[name] = N'test' AND t.[name] = N'Table3')
  AND NOT(s.[name] = N'usr' AND t.[name] = N'Table2')
```